# Почему не работает linewidth matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: График]

Я сделал приложения на KivyMD с интерактивным интерфейсом matplotlib, но толщина линий не меняется при значениях меньше 4, как только значение 4 и больше, то линия меняется, но почему?
key-ключ из словаря, но я не думаю что это влияет
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, antialiased=True, label=key)

Comment: А если antialiased=False, то толщина меняется?

Comment: @strawdog нет, мне кажется и antialiased тоже не работает

Comment: При чем здесь "кажется"? вы проверить можете?

Comment: @strawdog при antialiased=False не работает

Comment: Возможно 4 это минимальное значение которое можно отрисовать, отркойте код метода plot и посмотрите какие там дефолтные значения и ограничения

Comment: @Max нет, я запускал отдельно plot и значения 2 3 4 все отрисовывают по разному